# How to get the name of all the folders and subfolders of an Azure container

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I have this container Ofertas with 3 folders

[image]

within each of the 3 main folders there are hundreds of subfolders and within each of these subfolders are the files or blobs

[image]

I need to get the list of these subfolders but I only know how to get the principal folder names

```
string connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("ArchivadoHistoricoOfertas");
  BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
  BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("ofertas");

  var blobFolders = containerClient.GetBlobsByHierarchy(BlobTraits.None, BlobStates.None, "/").Where(b => b.IsPrefix).ToList();

  blobFolders.ForEach(f => {
    Console.WriteLine("Folder Prefix: " + f.Prefix);
  });
```

[image]

I have tried this

[image]

But here the code stops and nothing happens

[image]

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

If you need to get all folder, subfolder and files in structure you can use below code.

**Code:**

```
 class Program
        {
            static async Task Main(string[] args)
            {
                // Get a connection string to our Azure Storage account.
                string connectionString = "<connect strng>";
                string containerName = "test";

                Console.WriteLine($"Getting blobs and virtual directories for container '{containerName}'");

                BlobContainerClient container = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, containerName);
                await ListBlobsForPrefixRecursive(container,"", 0);
            }

            public static async Task ListBlobsForPrefixRecursive(BlobContainerClient container, string prefix, int level)
            {
                string spaces = new string(' ', level);
                Console.WriteLine($"{spaces}- {prefix}");
                await foreach (Page<BlobHierarchyItem> page in container.GetBlobsByHierarchyAsync(prefix: prefix, delimiter: "/").AsPages())
                {
                    foreach (var blob in page.Values.Where(item => item.IsBlob).Select(item => item.Blob))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{spaces} {blob.Name}");
                    }
                    var prefixes = page.Values.Where(item => item.IsPrefix).Select(item => item.Prefix);
                    foreach (var s in prefixes)
                    {
                        await ListBlobsForPrefixRecursive(container, s, level + 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**Output:**

[image]

If you need to get the particular root folder to get subfolder you use the below code:

**Code:**

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;


namespace storage326
    {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connectionString = "< storage account>";
            string rootfolder = "demo";
            List<string> subfolder = new List<string>();
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
            string containerName = "test";
            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
            var blobs = containerClient.GetBlobs(prefix: rootfolder);
            foreach (var blob in blobs)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(blob.Name);
                string[] sub_names = blob.Name.Split('/');
                if (sub_names.Length > 2 && !subfolder.Contains(sub_names[1]))
                {
                    subfolder.Add(sub_names[1]);
                }
            }
            foreach (var s in subfolder)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(rootfolder+"/"+ s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Console:**

[image]